Is there a way to get the traceback of an async function which was called with asyncio.gather and see which function called it?
The problem can be summarised in this example:
import asyncio
import traceback

async def func_c():
    print("func c")
    traceback.print_stack()

async def func_b():
    print("func b")
    tasks = [func_c() for _ in range(3)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    
async def func_b_v2():
    print("func b v2")
    tasks = [func_c() for _ in range(3)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def func_a():
    print("func a")
    await func_b()
    await func_b_v2()
    

async def main():
    await func_a()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

The problem I have is that traceback.print_stack() produces identical results if it were called by either func_b or func_b_v2 in their await asyncio.gather call.
The traceback looks something like:
File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
  asyncio.run(main())
File "asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
  return runner.run(main)
File "asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
  return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
File "asyncio/base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
  self.run_forever()
File "asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
  self._run_once()
File "asyncio/base_events.py", line 1919, in _run_once
  handle._run()
File "asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "test.py", line 6, in func_c
  traceback.print_stack()

Passing the traceback from function to function manually is not ideal because the func_c in my codebase is effectively used to log a result, but then be able to track the traceback of that result.
I have tried using other ways of calling multiple tasks concurrently
e.g.
using asyncio.create_task and using a for loop to await these tasks. This produces a similar result.
Similar issues did not help:
Python traceback for coroutine (does not use the asyncio.gather function)

I'm afraid no. The coroutine was not called in the usual sense. Instead a task was created and the scheduler ran it.
A function returns to the caller and the return address is stored in the stack, that's why a stack traceback shows this relationship. OTOH a task does not return to the caller. In general a task could be created anywhere in an async program and the created task can be awaited also anywhere, even at several places. There is no link with the desired information on the stack.
As a workaround (kind of), you could give a name to a task (or give it a specific context).
async def func_b():
    print("func b")
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(func_c(), name="created in func_b")
        for _ in range(3)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

To get the name given to the task:
taskname = asyncio.current_task().get_name()
print(taskname)


Creating a co-routine, or  task, is not a thing that is kept in the call stack (the chain of Frame objects) - so, no. Once created a task is an ordinary Python object that can be awaited. What each co-routine is awaiting for is introspectable, tough, through its cr_await attribute - and maybe it is possible to call asynco.all_tasks() , descend into each task's co-routine, and then find what could be awaiting your target task. However, I didn't find a way to go from finding an awaiting of a gather call to the tasks inside that gather. As I said, maybe that is introspectable, maybe not - and either way, it is not reliable, as it will depend on internal implementation of these async components.
However, it smells like you have a XY problem.
If in a sub-task you need access to some state that is present in a task that spawned it, without that being mixed with states that may exist in other instances of the same co-routine running in other tasks, the way Python has to separate it are "contextvars".
Check the stdlib contextvars module, and note that in asyncio docs, a lot of calls accept a "context" parameter (including .create_task) - so, it is feasible (though if not that easy) for a "super task" to convey information to all or specific subtasks without direct parameter passing, by using contexts and ContextVars .
If all a subtask has to know is if it was created in func_a or func_b (though not necessarily awaited there), this setup is possible:
import asyncio
#import traceback
import contextvars
import random

caller = contextvars.ContextVar("caller")

async def func_c():
    # randomize order after first round of calls.
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
    #print("func c")
    #traceback.print_stack()
    print(f"Func c, called from {caller.get()}")

async def func_b():
    print("func b")
    caller.set("func_b")
    tasks = [func_c() for _ in range(4)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def func_b_v2():
    print("func b v2")
    caller.set("func b v2")
    tasks = [func_c() for _ in range(4)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def func_a():
    print("func a")
    t1 = func_b()
    t2 = func_b_v2()
    await asyncio.gather(t1, t2)


async def main():
    await func_a()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
    
    

sample output:
$ python asyncxyz.py 
func a
func b
func b v2
Func c, called from func_b
Func c, called from func_b
Func c, called from func_b
Func c, called from func b v2
Func c, called from func b v2
Func c, called from func_b
Func c, called from func b v2
Func c, called from func b v2


If you really need this for traceback only, you could create a pair of decorators: one for marking the function in a ContextVar when running a function, and the other to get that name and annotate that inside a Frame in the traceback if an exception is raised.
